# Mule SMTP not sending any mails

Tags: smtp, gmail, mule, mule-studio

I have configured the outbound endpoint to the best of my knowledge but still the component is not able to send any mail.

I am using the latest Studio 3.7 to develop and the latest run-time

```
<smtp:outbound-endpoint host="smtp.gmail.com" port="465" user="aaa%40gmail.com" password="password" connector-ref="Gmail" to="zhk%40gmail.com" from="aaa%40gmail.com" subject="TestMessage" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SMTP" mimeType="text/plain" bcc="xyz%40gmail.com" cc="xyz%40gmail.com">
        <reconnect/>
    </smtp:outbound-endpoint>
```

Please note that this does not throw any errors .

Answer (score 1):

```
 <smtp:gmail-connector name="Gmail" contentType="text/plain" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Gmail"/>

<smtp:outbound-endpoint host="${smtp.host}" port="${smtp.port}" user="${smtp.from.address}" password="${smtp.from.password}" 
                                to="${smtp.to.address}" from="${smtp.from.address}" subject="${mail.success.subject}" responseTimeout="10000" 
                                doc:name="SuccessEmail" connector-ref="Gmail"/>


smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
smtp.port=587
smtp.from.address=youremail%40gmail.com
smtp.from.password=yourpassword
smtp.to.address=yourtoaddress@gmail.com
```

I think the port 587 should do the trick

This configuration is a tested/working configuration :)

Answer (score 0):

On the security tab of your SMTP component, enable SMTPS. Then try again.

If won't work, try removing '@gmail.com' on your user.